# odoo V8 External ID not found in the system on custom invoice report

Tags: python, xml, odoo-8, odoo

I am creating a module for Odoo V8 that prints a customized report, but for some reason it does not find some of the templates defined in the module and so far I do not know why.

Here is the content of the report (invoice):
 **Invoice**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
  <data>
      <template id="clusterbrands_custom_report_invoice">
        <t t-call="clusterbrands_custom_report_invoice">
            <div class="page">

                <div class="spacer" style="margin-top: 40px;"></div>

                <div class="row space-bottom">

                    <div class="col-xs-2">

                        <h3>
                            <b>Razon social: </b>
                            <span t-field="o.partner_id.name"/>

                            <br/>

                            <span t-if="o.partner_id.vat">
                                <b>R.I.F.: </b>
                            </span>

                            <span t-esc="o.partner_id.vat[2:]"/>

                            <br/>

                            <b>Telf:</b> <span t-field="o.partner_id.phone"/>
                        </h3>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-3">

                        <h3>
                          <b>Dirección Fiscal:</b> 
                                <br/>
                          <span t-field="o.partner_id.street"/>
                          <span t-field="o.partner_id.street2"/>
                                    <span t-field="o.partner_id.city"/>
                            <span t-field="o.partner_id.state_id"/>
                        </h3>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                 <h4> 
                          <div t-if="o.name" class="col-xs-4">
                              <p><strong> Descripción: </strong></p>
                              <span t-field="o.name"/>
                          </div>

                          <div t-if="o.origin" class="col-xs-4">
                              <strong> Doc. Origen: </strong>
                              <br/>
                              <span t-field="o.origin"/>
                          </div>

                          <div t-if="o.partner_id.ref" class="col-xs-4">
                              <strong> Codigo Cliente: </strong>
                              <br/>
                              <span t-field="o.partner_id.ref"/>
                          </div>

                          <div t-if="o.reference" class="col-xs-4">
                              <strong> Ref: </strong>
                              <br/>
                              <span t-field="o.reference"/>
                          </div>

                          <div t-if="o.user_id" class="col-xs-4">
                              <strong> Comercial: </strong>
                              <br/>
                              <span t-field="o.user_id" />
                          </div>
                                </h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
                              <h3>
                                <strong>
                                  <span t-if="o.type == 'out_invoice' and (o.state == 'open' or o.state == 'paid')">Factura</span>
                                  <span t-if="o.type == 'out_invoice' and o.state == 'proforma2'">PRO-FORMA</span>
                                  <span t-if="o.type == 'out_invoice' and o.state == 'draft'">Factura Borrador</span>
                                  <span t-if="o.type == 'out_invoice' and o.state == 'cancel'">Factura Cancelada</span>
                                  <span t-if="o.type == 'out_refund'">Reembolso</span>
                                  <span t-if="o.type == 'in_refund'">Reembolso Proveedor</span>
                                  <span t-if="o.type == 'in_invoice'">Factura Proveedor</span>
                                  <span t-field="o.nro_ctrl"/>
                                </strong>

                                <br/>

                                <strong>Fecha emisión:</strong> <span t-field="o.date_document"/>

                                <br/>

                                <strong>Fecha vcto:</strong> <span t-field="o.date_due"/>
                        </h3>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <table class="table table-condensed">

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Código</th>
                            <th>Descripción</th>
                            <th>Cant</th>
                            <th>Precio Unit.</th>
                            <th class="text-center" groups="sale.group_discount_per_so_line">Descuento (%)</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Sub total</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody class="invoice_tbody">

                        <tr t-foreach="o.invoice_line" t-as="l">
                            <td style="width: 10%"><span t-field="l.product_id.default_code"/></td>
                            <td style="width: 40%"><span t-field="l.name"/></td>

                            <td>
                                <span t-field="l.quantity"/>
                                <span t-field="l.uos_id" groups="product.group_uom"/>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <span t-field="l.price_unit"/>
                            </td>

                            <td class="text-center" groups="sale.group_discount_per_so_line"><span t-field="l.discount"/></td>

                            <td class="text-center">
                                <span t-field="l.price_subtotal" />
                            </td>

                        </tr>

                    </tbody>

                </table>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 pull-right">

                        <table class="table table-condensed">

                            <tr>

                                <td><strong>Sub total</strong></td>

                                <td class="text-right">
                                    <span t-field="o.amount_untaxed" t-field-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;monetary&quot;, &quot;display_currency&quot;: &quot;o.currency_id&quot;}"/>
                                </td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td><strong>I.V.A. <span t-esc="o.tax_line.name[:3]"></span></strong></td>

                                <td class="text-right">
                                    <span t-field="o.amount_tax" t-field-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;monetary&quot;, &quot;display_currency&quot;: &quot;o.currency_id&quot;}"/>
                                </td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td><strong>Total</strong></td>

                                <td class="text-right">
                                     <span t-field="o.amount_total" t-field-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;monetary&quot;, &quot;display_currency&quot;: &quot;o.currency_id&quot;}"/>
                                </td>

                            </tr>

                        </table>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <p t-if="o.comment">
                    <strong>Observaciones:</strong>
                    <span t-field="o.comment"/>
                </p>

                <p t-if="o.payment_term.note">
                    <strong>Forma de pago:</strong>
                    <span t-field="o.payment_term.note"/>
                </p>

                <p t-if="o.fiscal_position.note">
                    <strong>Fiscal Position Remark:</strong>
                    <span t-field="o.fiscal_position.note"/>
                </p>

            </div>
        </t>
    </template>

    <template id="report_template">
        <t t-call="report.html_container">
            <t t-foreach="doc_ids" t-as="doc_id">
                <t t-raw="translate_doc(doc_id, doc_model, 'partner_id.lang', 'clusterbrands_custom_invoice.clusterbrands_invoice')"/>
            </t>
        </t>
    </template>

  </data>
</openerp>
```

This is the entry of the report menu:
 **report.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
  <data>

    <!-- form view for company -->
    <report
        id="cluster_custom_invoice"
        model="account.invoice"
        string="Proforma (Media carta)"
        report_type="qweb-pdf"
        name="clusterbrands_custom_invoice.report_template"
        file="clusterbrands_custom_invoice.report_template"
        attachment_use="True"
        attachment="(object.state in ('open','paid')) and ('INV'+(object.number or '').replace('/','')+'.pdf')"
        />

        <record id="cluster_report_paperformat" model="report.paperformat">
            <field name="name">Media Carta</field>
            <field name="default" eval="True"/>
            <field name="format">custom</field>
            <field name="page_height">140</field>
            <field name="page_width">216</field>
            <field name="orientation">Portrait</field>
            <field name="margin_top">3</field>
            <field name="margin_bottom">3</field>
            <field name="margin_left">3</field>
            <field name="margin_right">3</field>
            <field name="header_line" eval="False"/>
            <field name="header_spacing">3</field>
            <field name="dpi">80</field>
        </record>

    <record id="cluster_custom_invoice" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
        <field name="paperformat_id" ref="cluster_report_paperformat"/>
    </record>

  </data>
</openerp>
```

and the order in which they are defined in the file "**openerp**.py":
 **openerp**

```
# any module necessary for this one to work correctly
'depends': ['base_setup', 'product', 'analytic', 'board', 'edi', 'report', 'account'],

# always loaded
'data': [
    'report/cluster_invoice.xml',
    'report/cluster_layout.xml',
    'report/cluster_footer.xml',
    'report/report.xml',
],
'css': [
    'static/src/css/style.css',
],
# only loaded in demonstration mode
'demo': [
    'data/demo.xml',
],
```

It does not matter how you define the ID for the report Odoo keeps giving me an error:

```
"External ID not found in the system: clusterbrands_custom_invoice.external_layout" while evaluating "translate_doc(doc_id, doc_model, 'partner_id.lang', 'clusterbrands_custom_invoice.clusterbrands_invoice')"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get it

```
  <template id="clusterbrands_custom_report_invoice">
    <t t-call="clusterbrands_custom_report_invoice">
```

Your template calls itself?
I guess you meant

```
  <template id="clusterbrands_custom_report_invoice">
    <t t-call="external_layout">
```

You can struggle with priorities with files loading change openerp.py to

```
'data': [
    'report/cluster_footer.xml',
    'report/cluster_layout.xml',
    'report/cluster_invoice.xml',
    'report/report.xml',
],
```

Comment: Thanks! you were right, the error was that i was trying to call a modified invoice template and i didn't change the name in the call.

Answer (score 0):

in template id you put the id like this:

```
<template id="clusterbrands_custom_report_invoice">
```

and the report template

```
<t t-raw="translate_doc(doc_id, doc_model, 'partner_id.lang', 'clusterbrands_custom_invoice.clusterbrands_invoice')"/>
```

the code should like this:

```
<t t-raw="translate_doc(doc_id, doc_model, 'partner_id.lang', 'clusterbrands_custom_invoice.clusterbrands_custom_report_invoice')"/>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but now the server throws me an error about an invalid ID:

"**Invalid template id: 'clusterbrands_custom_report_invoice**"